# Why can't the client obtain input again and again; it just goes blank after one input and one response from the server?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking, serversocket

**Client Side**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThreadClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final String HOST = "127.0.0.1";
        final int PORT = 4040;
        
        System.out.println("Client started.");
        
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4040);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Input: ");
            String input = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Sent: " + input);
            out.println(input);
        while(!"End".equals(input)){
                    System.out.println("Echoed from server: " + in.nextLine());
}
    
        }
    }
 
}
```

**Server Side**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThreadServer {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final int PORT = 4040;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        
        System.out.println("Server started...");
        System.out.println("Wating for clients...");
        
        while (true) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            Thread t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                        Scanner in = new Scanner(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                            String input = in.nextLine();
                            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                                break;
                            } else if(input.equals("Hi")){
                out.println("How are you?");
                } else if(input.equals("Bye")){
                out.println("Thankyou! Have a good day!");
                } else if (input != null) {
                        try {
                                String numbers;
                                numbers = input.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                                int number = Integer.parseInt(numbers);
                                out.println("The line is being printed");
                                for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                                out.println(input.replaceAll("[^a-z,^A-Z]", ""));
                           }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else {
        out.println("Sorry!");
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) { }
                }
            };
            t.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000L);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException xInterrupted) {
            // Ignore.
        }
        }
    }   
}
```

I'm adding one input on the client-side, and it's getting a response from the server, but when I attempt to insert another, it goes blank, showing that it's not accepting any further input from the client. So, can someone point me in the right direction as to where I went wrong with this code?

Comment: `while(!"End".equals(input))` <- You sure about that? Shouldn't that rather be an `if` instead of a `while`? Once that loop is entered it will never stop, because you don't change input inside the loop body. So once the condition is true it will stay true for ever

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS can you guide me on what changes should I make in the code, like you are saying instead of while loop, I should use if, but where, and what condition inside it

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS if I am using "if" instead of while, it is not giving the correct output result for the last else if condition on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably stuck in the nested while loop. The input never changes inside the nested while loop, so you'll never escape.

```
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Input: ");
        String input = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Sent: " + input);
        out.println(input);

        while(!"End".equals(input)){  // <-- Why the while loop?
                System.out.println("Echoed from server: " + in.nextLine());
        }    
    }
```

One option to fix it is to replace the `while(true)` loop with this:

```
    System.out.print("Input: ");
    String input = s.nextLine();
    while (!"End".equals(input)) {
        System.out.println("Sent: " + input);
        out.println(input);
        System.out.println("Echoed from server: " + in.nextLine());


        System.out.print("Input: ");
        String input = s.nextLine();
    }
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it's not working in the way I asked for.